# Twitter API log user out after tweeting

Tags: javascript, twitter

I need to let a user log into twitter and post a status, then after that log them out automatically.

I've looked through the Twitter API and could not find anything.

Current code:

```
 twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
        twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
            if(!code){
                jQuery('#voucher-container').show();
                var data = {sessionId: sessionId, type: 'twitter'};
                jQuery.post('checkTweet.php', data, function(response){
                    response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                    if(response.error){
                        alert(response.error);
                    }
                    else{
                        window.location.href = 'stage3.php';
                    }
                });
                code = true;
            }
        });
    });
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How about this answer from an old stack question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833889/use-twitter-api-to-log-user-out-of-twitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot log the user out from twitter through their API.

[Twitter API - Logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960957/twitter-api-logout)